# Double integrals and switching limits of integration?

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate $\int_0^1\int_x^1$ $1\over 1+x^2$ dy dx

According to the book, integrating this directly would not be practical because I would have to use arctan and a calculator. It reverses the order of integration and switches the limits instead.

$\int_0^1\int_0^y$ $1\over 1+x^2$ dx dy

When I tried solving this, I ignored the function and just looked at the limits of integration. I graphed y=x and then shaded in the upper region from y=(0,1). Then I changed the equation from y=x to x=y and then moved the limits like that. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Is the method I used to find the answer the proper way to do it?

Comment: It is correct. Congrats !

Comment: Thanks a ton NotALoner! =)

Answer (score 1):

Observe that one may evaluate your integral directly starting from the variable $y$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_x^1 \frac1{1+x^2} dy \:dx&=\int_0^1 \frac1{1+x^2}\int_x^1 dy \:dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac1{1+x^2}(1-x) \:dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac1{1+x^2} \:dx-\frac12\int_0^1 \frac{2x}{1+x^2} \:dx\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}4-\frac{\ln2}2.
\end{align}
$$